# Find all homomorphisms from $A_4, D_{2n}$ to $\mathbb C^\times$

Tags: group-homomorphism

I have a question that how to find all homomorphisms from

1. dihedral group $D_{2n}=\langle s,r :  s^2=r^n=1 ,  srs=r^{-1} \rangle$ to the multiplicative group $\mathbb C^\times$?
2. alternating group $A_4$ to the multiplicative group $\mathbb C^\times$?

I came up with a single approach to deal with the problems.

1. Note that $D_{2n}$ which is generated by $r, s$ so in order to specify a homomorphism from $D_{2n}$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$, we only need to say what happens to each of these elements. Assume that $\phi:D_{2n}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^*$ is a homomorphism, then $\phi(r)^n=1$, so $\phi(r)= \exp(2k\pi i/n)$, $k=0,\ldots,n-1$, and similarly $\phi(s)=\pm 1$. Thus we have $2n$ options for homomorphism $\phi$.
2. We know that $A_4=\langle (123), (234) \rangle$ and each of generator has order $3$. Using the similar arguments above we deduce that there are $9$ possible homomorphisms.

Do the above solutions look fine? Please light up my mind by your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As you figured out](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1477870/28900), the first part is not quite so simple. Neither is the second part.

Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be the two generators of $A_4$ that you mentioned. In particular, note that $\sigma\tau$ has order $2,$ and so if $f:A_4\to\Bbb C^\times$ is a homomorphism, then $f(\sigma)f(\tau)=f(\sigma\tau)\in\{1,-1\}.$ Given the possibilities for $f(\sigma)$ and $f(\tau),$ we conclude that $f(\sigma\tau)\ne-1,$ and so $f(\sigma)$ and $f(\tau)$ must be multiplicative inverses. This leaves $3$ possible homomorphisms $A_4\to\Bbb C^\times$. Checking the two nontrivial possibilities is straightforward.